# Error setting up mercurial on apache with win7 - DLL load failed

Tags: python, apache, mercurial

I am trying to setup Mercurial, publishing it through Apache on a Windows7 machine . These are the steps I have followed:

1. Installed Mercurial mercurial-2.0.0-x86.msi
2. Installed Apache Server - httpd-2.2.21-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8r.msi
3. Installed Python python-2.6.1.msi
4. Set up Apache to use Python through mod_wsgi - mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py26-3.3.so. Apache starts up fine till this point.
5. Created a directory called D:\hg\scripts
6. Unzipped the library.zip that comes with Mercurial here D:\hg\scripts\library_hg
7. Copy the templates directory from Mercurial to D:\hg\scripts\library_hg\templates
8. Setup a demo repository in D:\hg\hgrepos\demo1
9. Create a D:\hg\scripts\hgweb.config. Source:

   ```
   # An example WSGI for use with mod_wsgi, edit as necessary
   # An example WSGI for use with mod_wsgi, edit as necessary
   # See https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/modwsgi for more information

   # Path to repo or hgweb config to serve (see 'hg help hgweb')
   config = "D:/hg/scripts/hgweb.config"

   # Uncomment and adjust if Mercurial is not installed system-wide:
   import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "D:/hg/scripts/library_hg");
   #print sys.path;

   # Uncomment to send python tracebacks to the browser if an error occurs:
   #import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

   # enable demandloading to reduce startup time
   #from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()

   from mercurial.hgweb import hgweb
   application = hgweb(config)
   ```
10. My D:\hg\scripts\hgweb.config looks like:

    ```
    [web]
    style = coal

    [paths]
    / = D:/hgrepos/*
    ```
11. My config for Apache httpd.conf is:

    ```
    WSGIScriptAlias /hg "D:/hg/scripts/hgweb.wsgi"
    <Directory "D:/hg/hgrepos">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "D:/hg/scripts/">
        Options ExecCGI FollowSymlinks

        AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi

        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ```
12. When I try to access the hg script http://localhost:9000/hg, I get the following error:

    ```
    mod_wsgi (pid=3492): Target WSGI script 'D:/hg/scripts/hgweb.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
    mod_wsgi (pid=3492): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'D:/hg/scripts/hgweb.wsgi'.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:/hg/scripts/hgweb.wsgi", line 17, in <module>
        from mercurial.hgweb import hgweb
      File "mercurial\\hgweb\\__init__.pyc", line 10, in <module>
      File "mercurial\\hgweb\\hgweb_mod.pyc", line 10, in <module>
      File "mercurial\\ui.pyc", line 8, in <module>
      File "mercurial\\i18n.pyc", line 8, in <module>
      File "mercurial\\encoding.pyc", line 9, in <module>
      File "unicodedata.pyc", line 12, in <module>
      File "unicodedata.pyc", line 10, in __load
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
    ```

I have almost no knowledge of Python. I have been trying to find the cause of this error in various forums without success. Appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Giving up after spending days trying to figure out a solution. 
I have also tried building mercurial for windows without success.

I ran the same commands that are in hgweb.wsgi from python shell and I do not get the DLL errors.I think this thread outlines the issue which lies in the python distribution and not with mercurial:
http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/browse_thread/thread/fa72de2deef276d9

For some reason python running through apache and mod_wsgi is not able to find the DLLs in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads, you would download the Python 2.6 package, and delete the D:\hg\scripts\library_hg directory as that would waste space once you install this package and you can comment out the import sys line as well.

Also, on your config, you want [collections], not [paths] (and no *)

May not be needed but you get errors other than not being able to load modules, replace the last two lines of your hgweb.wsgi file with the following:

```
from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()
from mercurial.hgweb import hgweb, wsgicgi
application = hgweb(config)
wsgicgi.launch(application)
```

Comment: Also adding the line  "from mercurial import demandimport;"  causes a new error:  [Tue Dec 06 10:42:25 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "_ctypes.pyc", line 12, in <module>  
File "_ctypes.pyc", line 10, in __load  
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: The files I have used were (32-bit): Mercurial Python 2.6 package, python-2.6.6.msi (the change here shouldn't matter), Apache from ApacheLounge. I didn't use the mod_wsgi however. There might be a config you need to step to point to Python or something.